# How does the processing happen in a CPU when it uses Virtual Memory?

Tags: cpu, virtual-memory

I am just trying to visualize how computers work with Virtual Memory/Address.

Assume there is a program on the disk that looks like this:

`a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p` where the `a .. p` are instructions and their address is from `0` to `15`.

What happens inside the CPU while executing this program? Assume that the operating system uses `pages` of `8 bytes`.

To begin with, my understanding is that the operating system loads the program into physical memory in page-sized chunks and creates a mapping to the `pages` of the program numbered from 0..n which looks like:

```
# assume it is in reverse in the real memory (16-31)!

[i j k l m n o p] [a b c d e f g h]

# cpu's view of the program

  page1 (24-31)     page2 (16-31)
[a b c d e f g h] [i j k l m n o p]
 |
 PC
```

1. Depending on the program size, `program-size/page-size` `page`'s
   will be created. So here it would be `16B/8B = 2` pages numbered as
   page1 and page2.
2. Now, the Program Counter (PC) would be set to the Virtual Address of
   `a` which is `0` and the CPU will somehow resolve it and load the
   corresponding instruction from the real physical address of `a`
   which is `24` here.
3. But wait, how did CPU know that it has to look up into a certain
   page map, `page1` in this case? The operating system knows that but
   how does the CPU know that? Is it something like the Virtual Address
   of a program corresponds to one and only one page map and that can
   be determined directly from the Virtual Address itself? For example,
   `0x00` automatically means to lookup in `page1`, `0x08` means to
   lookup in `page2`. Divide by 8 and look into the `page{quotient}`
   with the remainder indicating the offset to look into the real
   memory?
4. Suppose there is an instruction `d` that refers to the memory
   corresponding to `o` which is in `page2`, how will that be resolved?
   Is it using the same principle? If you know the Virtual Address,
   then you know the place to look up for the real address?
5. Now, when there are multiple programs how do we uniquely determine
   what is `page1`? Could another program have a `page1` as well? Is it
   like page maps are unique (which I think is complex because I
   thought it has to be sequential and starting from 1 so that given a
   Virtual Address you can calculate the page map + offset) or is there
   a per process Page Table managed by the Operating System?
6. Suppose we finished executing the instruction `h`, the PC would
   automatically load the Virtual Address of `i`, which gets
   automatically resolved to `page2` using the same above principle?

Comment: Re, "...and the CPU will somehow resolve it..." Usually that is the responsibility of a _[Memory Management Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit)_ (a.k.a., "MMU") which is considered to be a separate functional unit from the CPU.  The MMU either _translates_ the upper bits of the virtual address to a physical address to which the memory can respond, or else it signals a _[page fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault)_ to the CPU.  It's the responsibility of the operating system to decide why a page fault happens and, how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual memory is handled just in the part of the CPU that handles reading and writing memory.

At some point, the CPU has calculated a memory address and has decided to read or write memory at that location. If there is no virtual memory used, then the memory address is the actual address in the physical memory connected to the CPU. With virtual memory, the memory access part of the CPU will first translate the virtual memory address to a real memory address.

Answer (score 0):

Your first step might be with two of the following books: [Design Unix Operating System](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132017997) or [Design Implementation FreeBSD Operating System](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321968972).

Also this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory and
this http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~phi/csf/slides/lecture-virtual-memory.pdf will help.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @xskxzr Really, in this case, I think the probelm is that the question is just too broad. The asker wants to know, essentially, "How does virtual memory work? You know, all of it." and that's just too much for a SE question.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, I understand it is a broad topic. Hence I made up a simple example and split it into six separate logical questions that a beginner can have so as to not be too vague about what I am asking. I am hoping all these ideas do a have a simple logical explanation at its core from where it is optimized and such.

Comment: @Nishant Numbering the separate parts of the question doesn't make it any less broad.